# BUILD FAILED in 16s Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1. i got this error while run the project

Tags: flutter, kotlin, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone64 arm64 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
../../FlutterDev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_chips_input-1.10.0/lib/src/chips_input.dart:87:7: Error: The non-abstract class 'ChipsInputState' is missing implementations for these members:

- TextInputClient.insertTextPlaceholder
- TextInputClient.removeTextPlaceholder
- TextInputClient.showToolbar
  Try to either
- provide an implementation,
- inherit an implementation from a superclass or mixin,
- mark the class as abstract, or
- provide a 'noSuchMethod' implementation.

class ChipsInputState extends State<ChipsInput>
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../FlutterDev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/text_input.dart:1124:8: Context: 'TextInputClient.insertTextPlaceholder' is defined here.
void insertTextPlaceholder(Size size) {}
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../FlutterDev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/text_input.dart:1127:8: Context: 'TextInputClient.removeTextPlaceholder' is defined here.
void removeTextPlaceholder() {}
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../FlutterDev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/text_input.dart:1116:8: Context: 'TextInputClient.showToolbar' is defined here.
void showToolbar() {}
^^^^^^^^^^^
../../FlutterDev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_math_fork-0.3.3+1/lib/src/widgets/selectable.dart:407:7: Error: The non-abstract class 'InternalSelectableMathState' is missing implementations for these members:

- TextInputClient.insertTextPlaceholder
- TextInputClient.removeTextPlaceholder
- TextSelectionDelegate.copySelection
- TextSelectionDelegate.cutSelection
- TextSelectionDelegate.pasteText
- TextSelectionDelegate.selectAll
  Try to either
- provide an implementation,
- inherit an implementation from a superclass or mixin,
- mark the class as abstract, or
- provide a 'noSuchMethod' implementation.

class InternalSelectableMathState extends State
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../FlutterDev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/text_input.dart:1124:8: Context: 'TextInputClient.insertTextPlaceholder' is defined here.
void insertTextPlaceholder(Size size) {}
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../FlutterDev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/text_input.dart:1127:8: Context: 'TextInputClient.removeTextPlaceholder' is defined here.
void removeTextPlaceholder() {}
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../FlutterDev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/text_input.dart:1041:8: Context: 'TextSelectionDelegate.copySelection' is defined here.
void copySelection(SelectionChangedCause cause);
^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../FlutterDev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/text_input.dart:1021:8: Context: 'TextSelectionDelegate.cutSelection' is defined here.
void cutSelection(SelectionChangedCause cause);
^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../FlutterDev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/text_input.dart:1029:16: Context: 'TextSelectionDelegate.pasteText' is defined here.
Future pasteText(SelectionChangedCause cause);
^^^^^^^^^
../../FlutterDev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/text_input.dart:1035:8: Context: 'TextSelectionDelegate.selectAll' is defined here.
void selectAll(SelectionChangedCause cause);
^^^^^^^^^
../../FlutterDev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/device_preview-0.7.4/lib/src/device_preview.dart:154:36: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.

- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../FlutterDev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
  orElse: () => WidgetsBinding.instance!.window.locale,
  ^
  ../../FlutterDev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/device_preview-0.7.4/lib/src/device_preview.dart:557:20: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../FlutterDev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
  WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback(
  ^
  ../../FlutterDev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/device_preview-0.7.4/lib/src/state/store.dart:81:26: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../FlutterDev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
  WidgetsBinding.instance!.window.locales,
  ^
  ../../FlutterDev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/device_preview-0.7.4/lib/src/views/device_preview_style.dart:86:50: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../FlutterDev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
  MediaQueryData.fromWindow(WidgetsBinding.instance!.window);
  ^
  lib/lifecycle_manager.dart:18:20: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '?.' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../FlutterDev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
  WidgetsBinding.instance?.addObserver(this);
  ^
  lib/lifecycle_manager.dart:24:20: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '?.' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../FlutterDev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
  WidgetsBinding.instance?.removeObserver(this);
  ^
  ../../FlutterDev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/device_preview-0.7.4/lib/src/utilities/media_query_observer.dart:26:20: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../FlutterDev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
  WidgetsBinding.instance!.addObserver(this);
  ^
  ../../FlutterDev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/device_preview-0.7.4/lib/src/utilities/media_query_observer.dart:32:20: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../FlutterDev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
  WidgetsBinding.instance!.removeObserver(this);
  ^
  ../../FlutterDev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/device_preview-0.7.4/lib/src/utilities/media_query_observer.dart:39:54: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../FlutterDev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
  data: MediaQueryData.fromWindow(WidgetsBinding.instance!.window),
  ^
  ../../FlutterDev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/device_preview-0.7.4/lib/src/views/tool_bar/toolbar.dart:31:30: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../FlutterDev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
  ? WidgetsBinding.instance!.window.padding.bottom
  ^
  ../../FlutterDev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/device_preview-0.7.4/lib/src/views/tool_bar/toolbar.dart:32:30: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../FlutterDev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
  : WidgetsBinding.instance!.window.padding.top);
  ^
  ../../FlutterDev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/device_preview-0.7.4/lib/src/views/tool_bar/toolbar.dart:40:30: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../FlutterDev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
  ? WidgetsBinding.instance!.window.padding.left
  ^
  ../../FlutterDev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/device_preview-0.7.4/lib/src/views/tool_bar/toolbar.dart:41:30: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../FlutterDev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
  : WidgetsBinding.instance!.window.padding.right);
  ^
  ../../FlutterDev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/persistent_bottom_nav_bar-4.0.2/lib/persistent-tab-view.widget.dart:368:22: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../FlutterDev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
  WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
  ^
  ../../FlutterDev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/persistent_bottom_nav_bar-4.0.2/lib/animations/animations.dart:55:20: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../FlutterDev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
  WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
  ^
  ../../FlutterDev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/persistent_bottom_nav_bar-4.0.2/lib/nav-bar-styles/style-6-bottom-nav-bar.widget.dart:44:20: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../FlutterDev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
  WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
  ^
  ../../FlutterDev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/persistent_bottom_nav_bar-4.0.2/lib/nav-bar-styles/style-8-bottom-nav-bar.widget.dart:44:20: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../FlutterDev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
  WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
  ^
  ../../FlutterDev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/persistent_bottom_nav_bar-4.0.2/lib/nav-bar-styles/style-11-bottom-nav-bar.widget.dart:46:20: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../FlutterDev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
  WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
  ^
  ../../FlutterDev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/persistent_bottom_nav_bar-4.0.2/lib/nav-bar-styles/style-12-bottom-nav-bar.widget.dart:46:20: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../FlutterDev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
  WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
  ^
  ../../FlutterDev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/persistent_bottom_nav_bar-4.0.2/lib/nav-bar-styles/style-13-bottom-nav-bar.widget.dart:46:20: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../FlutterDev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
  WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
  ^
  ../../FlutterDev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/persistent_bottom_nav_bar-4.0.2/lib/nav-bar-styles/style-14-bottom-nav-bar.widget.dart:46:20: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../FlutterDev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
  WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
  ^
  ../../FlutterDev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/provider-5.0.0/lib/src/inherited_provider.dart:391:26: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'SchedulerBinding' which excludes null.
- 'SchedulerBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart' ('../../FlutterDev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/scheduler/binding.dart').
  SchedulerBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
  ^
  ../../FlutterDev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/device_preview-0.7.4/lib/src/views/tool_bar/menus/popover.dart:141:20: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../FlutterDev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
  WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
  ^
  ../../FlutterDev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/device_preview-0.7.4/lib/src/views/tool_bar/menus/popover.dart:147:20: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../FlutterDev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
  WidgetsBinding.instance!.addObserver(this);
  ^
  ../../FlutterDev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/device_preview-0.7.4/lib/src/views/tool_bar/menus/popover.dart:152:20: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../FlutterDev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
  WidgetsBinding.instance!.removeObserver(this);
  ^
  ../../FlutterDev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/device_preview-0.7.4/lib/src/views/widgets/popover.dart:288:22: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../FlutterDev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
  WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
  ^
  ../../FlutterDev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/device_preview-0.7.4/lib/src/views/widgets/popover.dart:297:20: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../FlutterDev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
  WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) => _controller!.clear());
  ^
  ../../FlutterDev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_typeahead-3.2.7/lib/src/flutter_typeahead.dart:754:20: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../FlutterDev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
  WidgetsBinding.instance!.removeObserver(this);
  ^
  ../../FlutterDev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_typeahead-3.2.7/lib/src/flutter_typeahead.dart:767:20: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../FlutterDev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
  WidgetsBinding.instance!.addObserver(this);
  ^
  ../../FlutterDev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_typeahead-3.2.7/lib/src/flutter_typeahead.dart:803:20: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../FlutterDev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
  WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((duration) {
  ^
  ../../FlutterDev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_typeahead-3.2.7/lib/src/cupertino_flutter_typeahead.dart:558:20: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../FlutterDev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
  WidgetsBinding.instance!.removeObserver(this);
  ^
  ../../FlutterDev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_typeahead-3.2.7/lib/src/cupertino_flutter_typeahead.dart:571:20: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../FlutterDev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
  WidgetsBinding.instance!.addObserver(this);
  ^
  ../../FlutterDev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_typeahead-3.2.7/lib/src/cupertino_flutter_typeahead.dart:605:20: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../FlutterDev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
  WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((duration) {
  ^
  ../../FlutterDev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_chips_input-1.10.0/lib/src/chips_input.dart:137:20: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../FlutterDev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
  WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
  ^
  ../../FlutterDev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_chips_input-1.10.0/lib/src/chips_input.dart:288:22: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '?.' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../FlutterDev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
  WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
  ^
  ../../FlutterDev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_chips_input-1.10.0/lib/src/chips_input.dart:451:24: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '?.' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../FlutterDev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
  WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
  ^
  ../../FlutterDev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_math_fork-0.3.3+1/lib/src/widgets/selectable.dart:459:24: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'SchedulerBinding' which excludes null.
- 'SchedulerBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart' ('../../FlutterDev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/scheduler/binding.dart').
  SchedulerBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
  ^
  ../../FlutterDev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_math_fork-0.3.3+1/lib/src/widgets/selection/overlay_manager.dart:138:28: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'SchedulerBinding' which excludes null.
- 'SchedulerBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart' ('../../FlutterDev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/scheduler/binding.dart').
  if (SchedulerBinding.instance!.schedulerPhase ==
  ^
  ../../FlutterDev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_math_fork-0.3.3+1/lib/src/widgets/selection/overlay_manager.dart:140:26: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'SchedulerBinding' which excludes null.
- 'SchedulerBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart' ('../../FlutterDev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/scheduler/binding.dart').
  SchedulerBinding.instance!
  ^
  ../../FlutterDev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_math_fork-0.3.3+1/lib/src/widgets/selection/web_selection_manager.dart:119:24: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'SchedulerBinding' which excludes null.
- 'SchedulerBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart' ('../../FlutterDev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/scheduler/binding.dart').
  SchedulerBinding.instance!
  ^
  ../../FlutterDev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_math_fork-0.3.3+1/lib/src/widgets/selection/overlay.dart:141:26: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'SchedulerBinding' which excludes null.
- 'SchedulerBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart' ('../../FlutterDev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/scheduler/binding.dart').
  if (SchedulerBinding.instance!.schedulerPhase ==
  ^
  ../../FlutterDev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_math_fork-0.3.3+1/lib/src/widgets/selection/overlay.dart:143:24: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'SchedulerBinding' which excludes null.
- 'SchedulerBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart' ('../../FlutterDev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/scheduler/binding.dart').
  SchedulerBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback(_markNeedsBuild);
  ^
  ../../FlutterDev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_math_fork-0.3.3+1/lib/src/widgets/selection/overlay.dart:193:26: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'SchedulerBinding' which excludes null.
- 'SchedulerBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart' ('../../FlutterDev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/scheduler/binding.dart').
  if (SchedulerBinding.instance!.schedulerPhase ==
  ^
  ../../FlutterDev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_math_fork-0.3.3+1/lib/src/widgets/selection/overlay.dart:195:24: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'SchedulerBinding' which excludes null.
- 'SchedulerBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart' ('../../FlutterDev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/scheduler/binding.dart').
  SchedulerBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback(_markNeedsBuild);
  ^

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script '/Users/whitehatglobal/FlutterDev/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 1156
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command '/Users/whitehatglobal/FlutterDev/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 16s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: try without `flutter_chips_input`

Comment: how do i do this can you explain briefly

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.